# Printing Beta(Coef) alone from statsmodels OLS regression

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, time-series, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am running the linear regression function on a time series data of two stocks using statsmodels. While printing out the results using "summary", my code works fine. However I want to print only the beta(coef) of the two stocks. I tried using "params" instead of "summary" in the lines, but I keep getting the error message:

"TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"

I understand this is a very basic mistake, but i'm very new to coding. Any advice would be appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy.stats.mstats import zscore

df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\Sai\Desktop\DF.xlsx')

x = df[['Stock A']]
y = df[['Stock B']]

model = sm.OLS(zscore(x), zscore(y))
results = model.fit()
print(results.params())
```

This is the error message I keep getting:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python35-32\python.exe" C:/Users/Sai/Desktop/Quantstart.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sai/Desktop/Quantstart.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(results.params())
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.5.0/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html according to usage in example in that link(and the error message you are getting), it should be `results.params` without parentheses

Comment: Thanks Lafexlos! facepalming so hard... :)

Comment: Lafexlos,i've got another question. I am trying to replicate a code to backtest a strategy and the author uses OLS in pandas (0.12.0). But, i'm running it in statsmodels as I feel it is more appropriate. However, the code in pandas includes 'Lookback' argument to adjust the number of observations in the regression. And Iam not aware of the argument for 'Lookback' in statsmodels' OLS. Is there a specific argument to adjust the lookback period in the regression?

Comment: I literally have no idea. Sorry. It'd be better for you to ask a question about it if you think you've researched enough and create an [MCVE].

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code

```
results.params
```

instead of

```
results.params()
```

and it will work properly.